# Robot Framework Selenium | How to check if web page link is not the ${link}

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, robotframework

I'm having an issue while trying to test a creation process of a user, i.e. I should try different cases while creating users, with name, without name, with symbols in name and etc...

My issue is that when I press the "Create" button, In case if the user is created I'm getting navigated to the users page which link looks like this website.com/user/userid123123, so I have to check if the link is "website.com/user/registration" in case if I expect any issues, but how do I check if user is successfully created if I can't handle the id of user earlier then it is created.

In general, there is a keyword to check if link is the one I need which is 'Link Should Be ${link}'.

But I also need some keyword which does the opposite action like 'Link Should Not Be ${link}'.

I have tried looking in the web if there is a keyword like the one I need, but I found nothing, I also looked for another solution for my problem but in that case as well I found no solution.

Comment: Page should not contain textfield and a field from the registration form should work for your use case

Comment: @dot So I should just check if the field is no more on the page then it's success right ? That idea sounds great to me, thank you my friend! Case closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dot Helped out with this, the issue can be easily solved if the page won't contain the field, so by checking that you can be sure that the test is complete!